# How to call a servlet with buttons created dynamically

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I'll try to make a brief explanation, explaining in a clear and exhaustive the problem.

I have a JSP page that is invoked by a servlet. This JSP page generate a number of buttons according to the number of records returned by the servlet after a query (these records are passed through an ArrayList object, so if the ArrayList.size() it's 3, I'll generate 3 buttons; if 10, 10 buttons etc.), each button is positioned next to one another in a table and each row can have a maximum of 5 buttons.

**Now the real question is:** once I created these buttons, I need to call a servlet, but this servlet must know which button was pressed (For example, if there are 5 buttons, if I press the 3rd, I need to send to the servlet that I pressed the 3rd botton). How could I implement this? Could I do it through scripts in JavaScript? If possible, could you share me the code necessary for this purpose?

**Notes: the number of buttons is DYNAMIC, because the number of buttons varies every time. I can press just one button and the servlet must know which button was pressed. (If I press the 1th button, then return "1". If I press the 2nd button, then return "2". If I press the n° button, then return "n". I hope it is clear, now.**

*I hope I was clear to explain the problem, but I paste the part of the code relating to the generation of the buttons:*

```
<table class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <%
                    int buttons_number = 0;
                    int index = 0;

                    while(buttons_number< array.size()){
                %>
                        <tr> 
                            <%
                           while(index < 5 && buttons_number < array.size()){

                                String idChar = Integer.toString(index);
                            %>
                                 <td><input type="button" class="MyButton" id="<%=idChar %>"></td>   
                            <%
                                index++;
                                buttons_number++;

                            }

                            index= 0;

                            %>
                        </tr>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>

</table>
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because it's a different problem, a different question. I have not yet created a form and I highlighted "dynamically" on purpose, otherwise it would be easier and I would not have asked.

Comment: @BalusC Your duplicate didn't help me at all, because the issue of the other guy is different and has a static number of operations (function1, function2 and function3). my problem is to figure out which button has been pressed and your solution does not help me. I can have a huge number of buttons and I wont to create an if for each of them in the servlet, because the number of buttons changes everytime the number of records change. I can have 10, 100, 1000 buttons, I cannot go crazy creating 10, 100, 1000, 10 million of "if else if".

Comment: Huh? You don't have 10, 100, 1000, 10 million of hardcoded buttons. They are all dynamic. So just grab it dynamically, the same way. Anyway, I reopened the question. Good luck.

Comment: If you see, I put two while loops, look at the conditions: "while(buttons_number < array.size())" array is an ArrayList() and it can have 10, 100, 1000, in general, an huge number of elements that I don't know. The number of elements in this array varies depending on a query, previously made to a database; so if I have 10 records, I'll have a arrayList with .size() = 10 AND so I need to construct 10 buttons. 
This explains that I can have a number of buttons that change each time. Is the problem more clear to you now?

Comment: Thank you so much, I hope to solve, I'm totally stunned and I'm not able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I've changed:

```
<td><input type="button" class="MyButton" id="<%=idChar %>"></td>
```

Into:

```
<td><input type="submit" class="MyButton" id="MyButton" name="MyButton" value="<%=idChar %>"></td>
```

Then, when I will press a submit button I will call the doPost() method in the servlet and send the value of the button pressed.

```
String ButtonPressed = request.getParameter("MyButton");
```

Comment: That was already answered in the duplicate: just set name and value of button. Why do you think that your question is still different?

Comment: It's a little bit different because I've not a sequence of "If, then, else if", I didn't know that the request get the parameter of the button pressed, and not the other ones

Comment: Why didn't you listen and test/experiment and instead pretend to know it all better? You asked a question and needed help, right?